# PLSQL UPDATE BASED ON ROWS FROM OTHER TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have following tables in APEX A and B.

A has columns:

```
ID_A; 
VALUE;
```

B has columns:

```
ID_C_FK;
ID_A_FK
```

I want to update the `VALUE` column in table `A` in rows where `ID_A` equals `ID_A_FK` in selected rows from table `B` where `ID_C_FK` equal `x`

For example: `A` has rows (

```
ID_A  value
------------
  1     1
  2     1
  3     0
  4     0
  5     0
```

Table `B` has rows

```
ID_C_FK  ID_A_FK
------------------
  8         4
  9         4
  9         5
```

I want to update `VALUE` in table `A` only for those rows that have `ID_A` in rows selected from B and condition to select rows from B is that `ID_C_FK` equals `x = 9`; and as a result, table `A` should end up having rows:

```
ID_A  value
------------
  1      1
  2      1  
  3      0
  4      1
  5      1
```

How to write such update in PL/SQL?

Thank you for considering my request.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you say in in other words please ?

Comment: @horse with no name: Im doing project in apex, and I have to update tables after submitting with a button. I created such example to make problem clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
update a
    set value = 1
    where exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.id_a_fk = a.id_a and b.id_c_fk = 9
                 );
```

Comment: Why you put 1 after select ? I don't understand this: b.id_a_fk = a.id_a and b.id_c_fk = 9

Comment: This is a correlated subquery.  The `1` is just an arbitrary value to return something if there is a match.  The conditions on the `where` are to match the `join` conditions in the text for the two tables.

Comment: b.id_c_fk = 9 selects rows with idd_c_fk= 9, ok but how to understand meanig this: b.id_a_fk = a.id_a in contex of the code You've put. The idea is to update rows in A that are indicated by b.id_a_fk in rows that b.id_c_fk = 9

Comment: So the external part - update should set value only in rows with id's chosen from b rows with id_c_fk=9

Comment: @user3376246 . . . That is why there are two conditions.  The `id_a` needs to match `id_a_fk` *and* the value of the other column needs to be `9`.

Comment: OK, Your code works. I still don't know. Thank You for your involvement!

Comment: Subqueries and correlated subqueries are a basic part of the SQL language.  A place to start is with database documentation.  Oracle's is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries007.htm#SQLRF52340.  However, MySQL probably does a better job explaining them:   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/correlated-subqueries.html.

Comment: I understand id_c_fk=9 condition, but what is role of b.id_a_fk = a.id_a ? Why in select is written 'select 1' Could be any value or 1 has special meaning, it relates to 'set value = 1' ? im trying to translate it to my project case. i understand subqueries in select but in context of update i've problem.

Comment: As I commented earlier, it is an arbitrary value for the `exists` clause.

Comment: So in general update from subquery gets list of rows as if in normal select on table, and sets for every row in this list VALUE colum to passed in 'set VALUE=1'?

Comment: @user3376246 . . . Yes, I think your understanding is correct.  The `where` does the same thing in a `select`, `update`, or `delete`.  The value is being set by the `set` clause (and the `1` there has nothing to do with the `select 1` in the subquery).

Comment: OK, once again: Thank You for your involvement!